# No matching distribution found for coremltools

Tags: ios, coreml

I tried to use coremltools to convert caffemodel to mlmodel on my Mac.

Following the " pip install -U coremltools " , i got this:
"
Collecting coremltools
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement coremltools (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for coremltools
"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKEEf.png)

And, my python version is  "Python 2.7.10",
 numpy version is "numpy (1.12.1)",
protobuf version is "protobuf (3.2.0)"

i used " pip search coremltools ", and got " coremltools (0.3.0)  - Community Tools for CoreML ",
but  " pip install coremltools==0.3 " got " Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement coremltools==0.3 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for coremltools==0.3 "

wtf ? Does anyone get this as well ?

Comment: I got the same problem, too! A little different in environment with you is that I am under virtualenv with Python 3.5.2

Comment: Update: I use 'virtualenv --python=python2.7' to setup the environment to 2.7, then 'pip install coremltools' can successfully install the tool.

Comment: Tomjosun: sounds like an answer to me.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try installing coremltools in a virtualenv that runs Python 2.7. Note that it currently doesn't work with Python 3.x

[Installing virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/)

Once virtualenv is installed, create a new environment that runs Python 2.7

```
virtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python2.7 <DIR>
```

Next, activate the environment

```
source <DIR>/bin/activate
```

Then proceed with installing coremltools per usual

```
pip install -U coremltools
```

Comment: Quick note/update - as of March 2018, coremltools supports up to Python 3.6, but Python installed via Homebrew is 3.7, so you'll still have to work around that by using 3.6 instead of 3.7.

Answer (score 1):

I installed python 3.6 (i think all versions >= 2.7 will cause this problem). I had convert my default python version to 2.7 , but still not work.

And  i use another Mac with python version 2.7 as default, it did not appear again. and now , i installed coremltools successfully:

"  Collecting coremltools
  Downloading coremltools-0.3.0-py2.7-none-any.whl (1.4MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.4MB 171kB/s 
Requirement already up-to-date: numpy>=1.6.2 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from coremltools)
Requirement already up-to-date: protobuf>=3.1.0 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from coremltools)
Requirement already up-to-date: six>=1.9 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from protobuf>=3.1.0->coremltools)
Requirement already up-to-date: setuptools in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from protobuf>=3.1.0->coremltools)
Installing collected packages: coremltools
Successfully installed coremltools-0.3.0 "

Answer (score 1):

CoreMLTools requires Python 2.7
**coremltools-0.4.0-py2.7**
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/coremltools

1. cd ~/Virtualenvs
2. virtualenv *project_folder*
3. cd *project_folder*
4. source bin/activate
5. pip install -U coremltools

---

**Recommended Homebrew and Python Installation**
Homebrew Install (pre-Python Installation)
The macOS default PATH is **/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin**. You'll want to change it so that some Homebrew installations like Python will take precedence over stock macOS binaries. To make these changes, open ~/.bash_profile.
***vim ~/.bash_profile***
… and add these 4 lines:

*# Ensure user-installed binaries take precedence

export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH

 # Load .bashrc if it exists

test -f ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc*

Since the above directives will take effect on the next login, source the file to ensure it takes effect for the current session:

***source ~/.bash_profile***

---

Python and Virtualenvs Installations
brew install python
pip install virtualenv
mkdir -p ~/Virtualenvs
cd ~/Virtualenvs
virtualenv *project_folder*
cd *project_folder*
source bin/activate
pip install -U coremltools

---

Comment: Looks like coremltools now supports python3.x

Answer (score 0):

I was able to install it using virtualenv. Here is the details.

http://satoshi.blogs.com/ml/2017/06/installing-coremltools-on-macos.html

Answer (score 0):

I installed python 3.6x But i couldn't install coremltool with it. Work around it is to go for virtualenv.
If command: `pip install virtualenv` doesn't work just use latest command from python 3.6x i.e. `pip3 install virtualenv`.

Hopefully, it should work. Cheers